# Two containers - two Pythons - one site-packages?

Tags: python, docker

Let's assume I have two separate docker (or some other) containers which may only share folders with each other. There is a Python interpreter of the same version installed in both of these containers. Is there any way to make these interpreters to share almost the same PYTHONPATH, e.g. for both of them see all packages installed in any of these containers?

I know I can just import packages from a folder, but I want do find out if it's possible to do such steps:

1. Install package A in first container with pip or easy_install. This package may depend on other packages, which are located in second container and somehow mounted to first one. Also, there are some possible dependencies (which second container is missing) which will be installed into first container.
2. Inside second container import package A from first container without issues, so it should see both dependencies located in first and second containers.

The thing is, I'm trying to use [stevedore](http://stevedore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to look for packages by entry points, but they should be installed and, possibly, upgraded independently from what's installed in second container.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`basket`](http://pythonhosted.org//Basket/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood the question. If this does not answer your question, could you comment? To me there were like three questions you asked:

1. import behavior (I answered below)
2. Updating packages
3. stevedore - optional or not, a try or a requirement?

**Import Behavior**

There is a list called `sys.path`. It is the list of folders in which python looks for packages.
Suppose you have `folder1` and `folder2` in this list.

```
folder1
  +----- module_a
  +----- module_b

folder2
  +----- module_a
  +----- module_c
```

A Python process with `['folder1', 'folder2', ...]` as `sys.path` would do that:

```
import module_a # from folder1
import module_b # from folder1
import module_c # from folder2
```

A Python process with `['folder2', 'folder1', ...]` as `sys.path` would do that:

```
import module_a # from folder2 # difference
import module_b # from folder1
import module_c # from folder2
```

This is how I understand the Python import behavior. I do not use docker or PYTHONPATH, so I can not refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a container whose entry point creates a virtualenv in a volume and installs all the dependencies defined in a requirements file. Then you could use the --volumes-from flag to mount the virtual env in other containers and execute the activate script to import the environment..